# Why Skype consumes huge percentage of CPU?

Tags: cpu, skype, cpu-usage

I have searched this a lot using Google. I have found numerous people having the same problem as me, but I could not find any good answer anywhere. That's the reason I am asking it here as well.

Especially when Skype starts (but it does it also at other times), It consumes about 45% of my usage for a few minutes, and my computer becomes *very* slow.

I am not even using it, I just have it running at the backround.

It's performance is unacceptable for a background process, and the only program that manages to freeze my computer. Do you know how this could be fixed?

**Edit**
My skype's version is 6.11.0.102

Comment: What is your default browser.  There is a know bug dealing w with Skype and Chrome.

Comment: Skype belongs with IE like bacon belongs with eggs, cream with peaches, etc. They're both Microsoft products and Skype has developed a hatred for alternate browsers.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, My default browser is chrome. But I cannot understand, what does this have to do, with the fact that Skype uses such amount of CPU?

Comment: I explained the connection in my comment.  There is a **known bug** in Skype.  Its not clear if its Chrome or Skype itself that causes the problem.  There are multiple questions about this problem on this very website.

Comment: What Skype version are you currently using?

Comment: @and31415 Thanks a lot for your comment. It's 6.11.0.102. I will update my question as well.

Comment: Update it to the latest available version (6.13.0.104 right now), and see whether it makes any difference.

Comment: @and31415 hmmm... that's strange. When I try to update from Skype, A message is shown to me that says that I am using the latest edition

Comment: @JimBlum What if you uninstall the older version first?